# What is the use of empty classes in @jsonview?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I am new to ajax and json. Recently when I tried to use ajax and json implementation in Spring mvc. I came across tutorials using annotation like

```
@JsonView(Views.Public.class)
```

And below is the view definition

```
public class Views {
   public static class Public {}
   public static class Internal extends Public {}
}
```

Q1. What is the importance using Views.Public.class in @JsonView as Public class has no definition?

Q2. Why @jsonview is designed in this way?

Q3. The view class does not have normal definition and also inner classes (Public and Internal) as well. What do you called such type of classes and when do you use usually? I have heard of marker interface in serialization but I have not heard like marker class.

I am asking these question because I have never learnt such coding methology in java. Is it a kind of design pattern?

Comment: Have you read http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews? What don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

@Angom The reason is a combination of things. To start, Java annotation values can have only a very limited set of types; simple primitives (`int`, `boolean`, `long`), `String`s, Enum values, `Annotation` types or `Class`es.

So the choice of value type for logical Views is bit limited, when used with annotations. Many developers would choose Strings, but Classes actually have one nice benefit: composability. Since you can extend Classes and interfaces, you can have derived "child-views"; and checking for inclusion criteria (by Jackson) is very fast.

Now: if you only need view ids, then an empty interface or Class works just fine: you really just need the id, and possible inheritance hierarchy. There is no need to add methods or values.

It is, however, possible to use regular full classes as well, or add methods in these classes. View functionality makes no use of these; it does not care. So you could use existing classes/interfaces as View ids if you wanted to.

But since there isn't much cost to having empty classes, it is often cleaner to separate actual code and view classes.